# Updating, Deleting or Inserting records based on match with Integer

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

The below inserts a Project Month record for each month between a Project kickoff and deadline date.

I now need to update existing Project Month records whenever one of the Project dates are changed. But obviously the range of months could change so -

- If there's an existing Project Month record, I need to update it's Project_Value__c field.
- If there's not an existing Project Month record, I need to insert one.
- If there's an existing Project Month record but it's for a month which is no longer in the range of Project dates, it needs to be deleted.

I know that I could just delete all of the existing records and insert new ones but I guess it's best practice not to.

I should be able to match Project Month records based on their month & year with an integer value, in a similar process to the one that I've used to create the newPMs records.

But now that I have the integers to match with my existPMs, I'm struggling to work out how to run through that list and process the results?

```
trigger ProjectLifecycle on MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c (after insert, after update) {

    List<WEID__c> weids = WEID__c.getall().values();
    Set<Id> validRecordTypeIds = new Set<Id>();

    // add Project Record Type Ids from Custom Setting to list of valid Ids      
    for(WEID__c weid: weids) {
        try {
            validRecordTypeIds.add(weid.WEProjectId__c);
        } catch (System.StringException e) {
            System.debug(
                System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,
                'Invalid Record Type Id ' + weid.WEProjectId__c
            );
        }
    }

    List<MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c> insProjects = new List<MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c>();
    List<MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c> upProjects = new List<MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c>();
    Map<Id,Integer> projectDuration = new Map<Id,Integer>();
    Map<Integer,String> monthName = new Map<Integer,String>{1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March', 4 => 'April', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'June', 7 => 'July', 8 => 'August', 9 => 'September', 10 => 'October', 11 => 'November', 12 => 'December'};
    List<Project_Month__c> newPMs = new List<Project_Month__c>();
    List<Project_Month__c> existPMs = new List<Project_Month__c>();

    for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c p : Trigger.New){

        //check that Project record type is valid
        if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(p.RecordTypeId))
        {
            try{
                MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c oldP = Trigger.OldMap.get(p.Id);

                if(oldP.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c != p.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c
                   ||
                   oldP.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c != p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c)
                {
                    upProjects.add(p);
                    projectDuration.put(p.Id, p.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c.monthsBetween(p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c));
                }
            //if old.Map is null, record has been inserted & project months should be added
            }catch(system.NullPointerException e){
                insProjects.add(p);
                projectDuration.put(p.Id, p.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c.monthsBetween(p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c));
            }
        }
    }

    if(insProjects.size() > 0){

    for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c p : insProjects){

        Date k = p.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c;
        Integer km = p.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c.month();
        Integer dur = projectDuration.get(p.Id);

        //create a set of Project Month records for each Project
        for(Integer m = km; m < km + dur + 1; m++){

            Project_Month__c pm = new Project_Month__c();
            pm.Project__c = p.Id;
            pm.Name = monthName.get(m)+' '+ k.addMonths(m - 1).year();
            pm.month__c = k.addMonths(m - km + 1).toStartOfMonth() - 1;
            pm.Project_Value__c = p.Opportunity_Total_Net_FSR__c;
            newPMs.add(pm);
        }
    }
    insert newPMs;
    }

    if(upProjects.size() > 0){

        for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c p : [SELECT Id,
                                                 (SELECT Id FROM Project_Months__r) FROM MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c
                                                   WHERE Id IN :upProjects]){
                                                       existPMs.add(p.Project_Months__r);
                                                   }

        for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c p : upProjects){

            Date k = p.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c;
            Integer km = p.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c.month();
            Integer dur = projectDuration.get(p.Id);

            for(Integer m = km; m < km + dur + 1; m++){

                //attempt to match Project Months here?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would seem that your question is more one of sitting down and blocking out the logic of how you'll approach the problem rather than one of writing code. If projects change, I'm guessing that it's the end dates that change, but you'd know better than I. If that's the case, they either get longer or shorter. Does that help? If both can change, you have a much more complex problem to deal with where deleting and repopulating would likely be more efficient.

Comment: @crmprogdev thanks, the point about only Project deadlines changing is good. But in my case it's quite likely that both will change & I'd like to cover that scenario. Doing an update may be more trouble than it's worth but I'm hoping that there's someone who's come up with a way to manage this type of process before..figuring out how to manage no matches for the integer or no matches for the Project Month is the key (obviously managing a match is the easy one).

Comment: If they both change, doesn't that mean that every one of your entries will at a minimum need to be updated and that it's possible, if not even likely, that some will need to be deleted? I'll leave it to you to draw your own conclusions about what that might suggest or imply...

Comment: geez, I'd delete them all and reinsert. Logic is much simpler and performance impact will be minimal. Instead of debugging complex logic, get on with your no doubt endless list of other to-do's